# Does pip share the same versions of a package given a maintenance version of Python?

Tags: python, pip

It seems that many projects provide only an indication of the minor python version (e.g. `python 3.6`), whereas requirements.txt may require a specific version of a package (e.g. `torch==0.4`).

This specific version of a package is not available for any minor python version (e.g. `torch==0.4` can be installed only with python 3.5 ou 3.6).

But what happens with maintenance Python versions? (e.g. python 3.6.9). Can we assume that `torch==0.4` will always be distributed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python project distributions (libraries, packages, applications) are meant to be compatible with all *maintenance* releases of the same *minor* version of the Python interpreter (in *3.6.9*: *3* stands for the *major*, *6* for the minor, and *9* for the *maintenance* or *bugfix*). In other words if a library is advertised as compatible with Python 3.6, it means it is compatible with all Python *3.6.** versions (3.6.0, 3.6.1, 3.6.9, etc.). On the other hand there is no guarantee it is compatible with *3.7.**, *3.5.**, or even less so with *2.** or *4.**.

Comment: Ok but it is just compatible or also distributed with any maintenance versions?

Comment: I do not understand the question. -- _pip_ will be able to figure out which distributions are compatible with the Python interpreter, and decide whether or not to download and install.